# Can a closed path be homotopic to a point outside of its inclosure?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

My question is if I have some closed path $\gamma$ is it possible for it to be homotopic to a point $z_0$ if that point $z_0$ lied outside of $\gamma$'s inclosure? And if yes, how does one interpret this visually?

Edit: I think it could be useful for me to include the definition that I use for homotopy:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. Take, for instance,$$\begin{array}{rccc}\gamma\colon&[0,2\pi]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&t&\mapsto&e^{it}\end{array}$$and $p=2+2i$. Now, consider the homotopy$$\begin{array}{rccc}H\colon&[0,2\pi]\times[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&(t,u)&\mapsto&(1-u)e^{it}+u(2+2i).\end{array}$$This shows that $\gamma$ and the constant path which is always equal to $p(=2+2i)$ are homotopic in $\Bbb C$. You can visualize this as a family of circles going from the circle centered at $0$ with radius $1$ to the “circle” centered at $p$ with radius $0$.

Comment: Hi @José Carlos Santos thank you for the answer. I have two questions. First, when considering the family of circles is it assumed that they can change side so that the family is contained in the set? And lastly, is homotopy then a transitive property?

Comment: to add on my previous comment, I have tried proving that homotopy is transative and I have arrived at a proof that defines a new function that is piecewise made from the original two, does this work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking!  A simple closed curve is "homotopic" to a closed point because it can "collapse" down to a point.  And every point is "homotopic" to every other point!  A simple closed curve is homotopic to **any** point, not some specific point, so it doesn't matter is a point is inside or outside the curve.

Comment: Hi @user247327, my question is targeted to the last sentence of your answer. I am asking how can a closed path be homotopic to a point outside of its inclosure? - I can't interpret this result visually and intuitively, as you have mentioned, I think about collapsing to a point, but I always envisioned this point being in the region defined by the curve, not outside.

Comment: You may be dealing with a more restricted notion of "homotopy" than I am.  Yes, a simple closed curve can be contracted to a point within it but I am allowing a translation as well when I say "every point is homotopic to every other point" since any point can be translated to another.

Comment: Hi @user247327, I have not met translations between points in that context so far in my study so far. I have included my current definition of homotopy to the question.